# Nested select in sql error Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql

i try to execute this query:

```
select *, (select * from tab1 where tab1.type!="firstype") as P
from tab2 where tab2.attr="something" and tab2.tab1_id=P.id
```

But i have this error:

```
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)    0,001 sec
```

i understand the error but not why come out. P.id not work?

Comment: You can't use a subquery yielding multiple columns that way. Try selecting only the ID field.

Comment: (I.e. `select id from tab1 ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1 P, Tab2
WHERE tab2.tab1_id=P.id
AND tab2.attr = "something"
AND tab1.type != "firstype"
```

Comment: ok but P.id not work, so if i try with: from tab1,tab2 where tab2.tab1_id=tab1.id... works

Answer (score 0):

You have the `from` clause in the wrong place.  And, you should use explicit `join` syntax.  Among other things, it will help prevent this type of error:

```
select *
from tab2 join
     tabl p
     on tab2.tab1_id = P.id and
        tab2.attr = 'something' and
        p.type <> 'firstype';
```

You also don't need the subquery.  The filtering conditions can go in the `on` or in a `where` clause on the outer query.